# Migrating MongoDB from localhost to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-applications, backend

I completed development of a web application for my university doing everything on **localhost**. Now I want to **migrate the backend and the MongoDB** to the stakeholder's (my university) server environment. I tried finding different ways to do so but I haven't found a solution. Please help me in resolving this. Any links and working examples or videos would help a lot.

Tech stack used for backend: 
1. NodeJS
2. MongoDB 
3. google maps client api

Comment: What’s the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a database software interface like 
Studio 3T, Robot3T or any others that have a backup and/or export and/or import feature.

If you have access to the machine and can install tools for MongoDB there are some terminal tools to do this.

Mongo Import
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

Mongo Export
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#bin.mongoexport